# How can you insert data into a ARRAY column on a Snowflake table using SQL?

Tags: insert, array, snowflake

I am having difficultly finding documentation on how to insert data into an ARRAY column type using SQL on a Snowflake table.

Snowflake Documentation: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#array

```
// example table
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE array_test_table (
  id number,
  ids array
);

// This does not work
INSERT INTO array_test_table (id, ids) 
VALUES (1, '[1,2,3]' );
```

I have tried using using postgres's syntax like ones described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335338/inserting-array-values

I originally asked this question here: [Snowflake Community](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008MqR8pSAF/how-do-you-insert-data-into-a-table-with-column-type-array-using-sqlhttpsdocssnowflakenetmanualssqlreferencedatatypessemistructuredhtmlarray?t=1536851146056)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to apply a function to parse the array. As of 9/13/2018 functions are not allowed in value lists see [Is there a literal syntax for arrays](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008AI1sHSAT/is-there-a-literal-syntax-for-arrays)

One way around this is to combine INSERT INTO and SELECT statement. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE array_test_table (
  id number,
  ids array
);

INSERT INTO array_test_table (id, ids) 
SELECT $1, PARSE_JSON($2)
  FROM VALUES (1, '[1,2,3]' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,2,3)` instead of parsing JSON.

```
INSERT INTO array_test_table (id, ids) 
SELECT 1, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,2,3) ;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html